# Iteration C++ string of 6 numbers

Tags: c++, iteration

I want something like this:

```
int main(){
    std::cout << "(";
    for (int a = 12, i = 0; i < 6; i++, a -= 4){
        std::cout << a << ((i < 6) ? ", " : ")");
    }
}
```

String of 6 numbers in order: 12,8,4,-4,-8,-12
but without 0 inside and -12 at the end. What thing I have to implement for this to work?

Comment: Where is  a string in your code?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think he meant this *String*: "a sequence of similar items".

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the `i` variable entirely. Just iterate over the values you want to print out. This is easy since it's an arithmetic sequence.

```
int a = 12;
for (; a > -12; a -= 4)
{
    std::cout << a << ", ";
}
std::cout << a;
```